# Resetting the .one('click') after doing something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, timeout, reset

To prevent firing an event twice in a row, is it possible to do something like this?

```
$('.examplediv').one('click', function() {
    //doing a bunch of stuff
    //somehow rebind the .one('click') <------
});
```

I want to reset the .one('click') after I have //do some stuff so that the entire event can be fired again.

-edit-

I tried RocketHazmats solution,

```
$('.examplediv').on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).data('click_running')){
        $(this).data('click_running', true);
        //doing a bunch of stuff
        $(this).data('click_running', false);
    }
});
```

But the //doing a bunch of stuff still fires more than once if I double-click it really quick.

If I do it with a timeout, should it look like this then?

```
$('.examplediv').on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).data('click_running')){
        $(this).data('click_running', true);
        //doing a bunch of stuff
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).data('click_running', false);
        }, 2500);
    }
});
```

While it atleast doesn't fire it twice in a row if I double-click it, with the above code I can never press it again despite the timeout? Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: e.preventDefault or .stop() <- you really need to give us more info than that

Comment: You want to fire click event only once for all '.examplediv' elements or what is your question?!

Comment: @A.Wolff: I think he wants to block the click event while it's running on an element.

Comment: You are asking if you can rebind a new/same one("click") event?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to rebind the same one.click event.

Comment: @Hrodebert Do you just want a delay before the element is clickable again? You could use RocketHazmat's answer with a `setTimeout()` to delay changing the "running" flag back to false.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$('.examplediv').off('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a "running" flag to the element, to block the event if it's already running.

```
$('.examplediv').on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).data('click_running')){
        $(this).data('click_running', true);
        //do some stuff

        //make the .examplediv accept another click event?
        $(this).data('click_running', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that if you double-click fast, it will still fire the event twice. Most users won't double-click but I still don't want that to be possible. with the one.click it is not possible to double-click but it is also not possible to click it again later, thats why I want to rebind the one.click if it is possible.